# How do I find a base of orthogonal complement $U^\perp$ of $U$ and determine the dimension of $U^\perp$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let U be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$, which is through $(1,2,3,-1,2)^T$ and $(1,0,-1,0,1)^T$ spanned.

How do I find a base of orthogonal complement  $U^\perp$  of  $U$ and determine the dimension of $U^\perp$?

Comment: Hint: Can you find any vectors which are orthogonal to all vectors in $U$?

Comment: Yes. Done that.

Comment: With Grahm-Schimdt.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Denote $e_1,e_2$ the two given vectors and complete the family $(e_1,e_2)$ on an arbitrary basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5)$ of $\Bbb R^5$. Now use [the Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to construct an orthogonal basis $(v_1,\ldots,v_5)$ and then $U^\perp=\operatorname{span}(v_3,v_4,v_5)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Instead of using Gram-Schmidt, you can write the conditions that a vector $v$ is orthogonal to the two given vectors as a system of equations.  Then, by reducing the system of equations, you have the answer you're looking for.